# I want the user to input a list of dictionaries and then will followup and do some searching functions, however userinput becomes a string

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I want the user to input something like (refer below to data to paste) and assign it to the value performance directly as a list of dictionaries and this will be assigned to a variable called performance.

I do not want to make the user individually add item by item and update it into a list, they should just paste the data below

i want to use pure python or some light library like sys (built in only allowed), please help

What I have written below gives me an error when trying to extract values etc. since it is automatically stored as a string:

> performance = (input('Enter your database as a list of dictionaries: '))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval), which parsed and evaluated the string provided in python syntax:

```
inp = input('paste :')
data = eval(inp)

print(repr(data))
```

p.s. Beware of code injection while using eval().

Comment: This works, thanks so much! Can i check how do i prevent code injection? is it using some try-else statement?

Comment: If you write the code for yourself to make your work easier, then it should be fine, but if your code will be used by other parties, you should sanitize the user input.  [See this](https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-python-applications-5d4cd541b3f1)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing, this was a very useful and helpful article! Since I'm using python 3 - based on the article i dont need to change the input () type to raw_input () from what i understand